# advanced search in tex files

Tags: best-practices, editors, texshop

Is there a way to perform advanced search queries within tex-files? What I mean by "advanced search query" is all queries that cannot be performed with only a single search term.

For example, it is easy to "show all `\emph` commands that follow a comma" by simply searching for `, \emph`, but what about more advanced tasks like:

> "show me all instances where the value of the `\emph` command *contains* a comma" or
>
> "show me all instances where the `\emph` command *is followed by* a comma".

This is just an example. I can think of many other queries that might come in useful when working with Latex.

What triggered this question: I know a bit about working with `xml`-files in Oxygen and about the `XPath` search options. For Latex, I use `TexShop` where I can choose between three different find panels: Apple search bar, apple search panel and Ogrekit. Ogrekit is more advanced, so I thought that one could perform "advanced search queries" with that. But I don't know how.

Having said that, I would prefer answers about `TexShop` and `Ogrekit` but in general I'd be happy for any hints for how to search for more complicated patterns within my documents.

Comment: This sounds really like a general text editor question. Most 'advanced' editors allow regular expression searching, and that is the approach I think that is best suited to this type of query.

Comment: Indeed, I was unsure whether or not the question really fits the scope of this site. In any case, however, it is somehow a question about best practice and handling large documents. Maybe there are tricks and hints that can be useful.

Comment: So, do you want to know how to perform a regexp search?  You don't even need an editor to do that, `grep` suffices.

Comment: @JosephWright Is it possible to migrate this to Emacs.SE? I cannot remember if that is possible with Beta sites.  At any rate, this belongs there.  I would recommend the use of Helm for interactive searching.  `helm-swoop`, in particular, allows some great fuzzy searching (albeit without regular expressions to my knowledge).  There are also `helm-grep` and `helm-ag`.

Comment: @SeanAllred Question isn't about Emacs, so would be inappropriate to migrate, beta or not.

Comment: @JosephWright I misread – Rather, I assumed based on the tag. My apologies :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is regular expression search built into TeXShop.  So, using the example text in the SeanAlred's answer, we can search for instances of the use of `\emph` as follows:

[image]

Hitting `Next`(or CONTROL-G) repeatedly:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Booooo :) I don't have TeXshop installed, but yay for screenshots!  Pretty slick that TeXshop uses PCREs.

Comment: Why does it count lines like that? Those aren't hard line breaks, are they?

Comment: @cfr: Hmmmm... Yeah they are hard line breaks -- cut and past the text from SeanAllred's answer and you'll see.

Answer (score 3):

Also Emacs' regexp engine is able to match multi-line pattern, so the regexp provided by Sean, adapted to Emacs syntax, works here:

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with normal `grep`, but can be done with `pcregrep`, which is pretty standard on modern Linux distributions.

```sh
$ pcregrep -M '\\emph{[^}]*,' file.tex
  multiple lines.  See a \emph{really, really
  good tutorial} on \emph{unix, commandline}.
Here is an \emph{that spans a couple lines but
  unfortunately, the comma is on another line}
```

`file.tex` contains

```
This is a basic text file.
It contains many lines, some of which span
  multiple lines.  See a \emph{really, really
  good tutorial} on \emph{unix, commandline}.
Here is an \emph{that spans a couple lines but
  unfortunately, the comma is on another line}
```

It is unlikely that you're going to find an editor without PCRE regex support that can do this.

Comment: Don't judge my example file :) I'm not well.

Comment: If you don't introduce arbitrary hard line breaks, `grep` is good enough ;).

Comment: @cfr and version control would be all but useless :)

Comment: @SeanAllred  Emacs's regexp engine is able to match those lines with the regexp you provided `;-)`

Comment: And see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7167115/2442087 for how to use plain `grep` to match multiline patterns.

Comment: @SeanAllred I don't break mid-sentence, though. So for this example, `grep` is fine. Kile's search can cover line breaks. Otherwise, I'd use `sed` or `gawk`. (But I'd never heard of `pcregrep` until you mentioned it.)

Comment: @cfr related if you use emacs :) http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/5330/2264

Comment: @SeanAllred What's emacs? Is it like vim? ;)

Comment: @cfr even better! ;)